# Рандомный оттенок

Tags: jquery, цвета

Хочу создать форму, где пользователь нажимает на нужный цвет и скрипт генерирует случайный оттенок этого цвета.

Я генерирую цвет *rgb* с помощью `random`. Но я не могу Придумать, как сделать, что бы генерировался именно оттенок цвета, а не случайный цвет

```js
$(function() {
  $('#color').change(function() {
    var min = 0, max = 255;
    
    var rgbColor = 'rgb('+(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min)+','+(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min)+')';
    
    $('#shade').val(rgbColor).css('border-color', rgbColor);
  });
});
```

```css
#shade {border: 2px solid #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Выберите цвет: 
  <select id="color">
    <option style="display: none;">Выбрать цвет...</option>
    <option value="red">Красный</option>
    <option value="green">Зелёный</option>
    <option value="yellow">Жёлтый</option>
    <option value="blue">Синий</option>
    <option value="grey">Серый</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  Оттенок:
  <input type="text" id="shade">
</p>
```

Как сделать, что бы генерировался оттенок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно записывать кода всех оттенков нужных

```js
$(function() {
  $('#color').change(function() {
    var self = this,
        // Создаём список цветов
        colorsModels = {
          'red': {'r': '50-255', 'g': '0', 'b': '0'},
          'green': {'r': '0', 'g': '50-255', 'b': '0'},
          'yellow': {'r': '50-255', 'g': 'r', 'b': '0'},
          'blue': {'r': '0', 'g': '0', 'b': '50-255'},
          'grey': {'r': '50-200', 'g': 'r', 'b': 'r'}
        };
    // Проверяем, существует ли цвет указанный в списке
    if( colorsModels[self.value] !== undefined  ){
      // Передаём массив цвета в переменную и создаём rgb
      var model = colorsModels[self.value],
          rgb = {r: null, g: null, b: null};
      
      // Перебираем каждый цвет из массива
      for(var key in model){
        if( /\d{1,3}\-\d{1,3}/.exec(model[key]) ){ // Проверяем, указано ли значение диапазоном
          // Вычисляем минимум и максимум с диапазона
          var min = parseFloat( model[key].replace(/(\d{1,3})\-\d{1,3}/, '$1') ),
              max = parseFloat( model[key].replace(/\d{1,3}\-(\d{1,3})/, '$1') );
          
          // Вычисляем рандомное число в этом диапазоне
          var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
          
          // Применяем значение
          rgb[key] = value;
        }else if( /\d{1,3}/.exec(model[key]) ){ // Если цвет указан не диапазоном, то проверяем, цифра ли это
          // Преобразовываем значение в цифру
          var value = parseFloat( model[key] );
          
          // Применяем значение
          rgb[key] = value;
        }else if( model[key] === 'r' || model[key] === 'g' || model[key] === 'b' ){ // Проверяем, ну казано ли значение повторяющим цветом (не равно ли значение пердыдущим цветам)
          // Проверяем, на допустимость повторения
          if( (key !== 'r' && key !== model[key]) || (model[key] === 'g' && key !== 'r') ){
            // Если всё нормально, то копируем значение
            rgb[key] = rgb[model[key]];
          }else{
            console.error('Invalid!');
          };
        }else{
          console.error('Undefined a value color!');
        };
      };
      
      // Устанавливаем значение
      var rgbColor = 'rgb('+rgb['r']+','+rgb['g']+','+rgb['b']+')';
      
      $('#shade').val(rgbColor).css('border-color', rgbColor);
    }else{
      console.error('Undefined a color!');
    };
  });
});
```

```css
#shade {border: 2px solid #000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Выберите цвет: 
  <select id="color">
    <option style="display: none;">Выбрать цвет...</option>
    <option value="red">Красный</option>
    <option value="green">Зелёный</option>
    <option value="yellow">Жёлтый</option>
    <option value="blue">Синий</option>
    <option value="grey">Серый</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  Оттенок:
  <input type="text" id="shade">
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Обычно цвет переводят в цветовую модель [HSV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)), меняют оттенок цвета (Hue) и переводят обратно в RGB. Если нужно поменять насыщенность - Saturation. Если светлоту - Volume.

Посмотрите также другие цветовые модели - многие из них "заточены" под разные вещи.

Answer (score 1):

Для серого цвета надо выбросить один random, и выпавшее значение присваивать всем каналам (r,g,b).
Для прочих цветов генерировать значения не в полном диапазоне [0, 255], а раздельно по каналам, отдавая предпочтение тем или иным из них.

```
function limitedRandom (min, max)
{
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
}

red = {
    r: limitedRandom(150, 255);
    g: limitedRandom(0, 100);
    b: limitedRandom(0, 100);
};


yellow = {
    r: limitedRandom(150, 255);
    g: limitedRandom(150, 255);
    b: limitedRandom(0, 100);
};
// and so on
```

Конкретные границы диапазонов цветов подберите по своему вкусу в графическом редакторе.

Comment: Почему у вас у цветов везде рандом? Если в красный подмешать зелёный, то он станет жёлтым..

Comment: Если подмешать немного, то не станет, красный все равно будет доминировать. Возможно, 100 - слишком много, можно убавить, но рандом по всем каналам позволяет получить именно разные оттенки. Если нужнен просто чистый цвет разной интенсивности, пишите в g и b нули для красного, в b для жёлтого и т.п.